# Read clickhouse configured port numbers from inside

Tags: clickhouse

Are there any possibility to read clickhouse's ports?
TCP port information can be read from `system.clusters` table, but I need to figure out http port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getServerPort](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#getserverport) function:

```sql
SELECT getServerPort('http_port')

/*
┌─getServerPort('http_port')─┐
│                       8123 │
└────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Take into account that this function is available starting from version [21.10](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2021/#clickhouse-release-v2110-2021-10-16).

---

```sql
SELECT
    tcpPort() AS tcpPort,
    getServerPort('tcp_port'),
    getServerPort('http_port')

/*
┌─tcpPort─┬─getServerPort('tcp_port')─┬─getServerPort('http_port')─┐
│    9000 │                      9000 │                       8123 │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
*/
```