# how to check my port_number of clickhouse

Tags: python, csv, connection, clickhouse

I want to know my port of clickhouse for inserting my csv files into into clickhouse.
SHOW SETTINGS; command is not showing the port numbers.

I want to insert my csv files into clickhouse using python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read clickhouse configured port numbers from inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569103/read-clickhouse-configured-port-numbers-from-inside)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running ClickHouse server locally you can check the open ports with the following command

```
sudo lsof -p $(pgrep clickhouse) -i -Pan

COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
clickhous 77385 ryadh    6u  IPv6 0x90e12861e86522d5      0t0  TCP [::1]:8123 (LISTEN)
clickhous 77385 ryadh    7u  IPv6 0x90e12861e86531d5      0t0  TCP [::1]:9000 (LISTEN)
clickhous 77385 ryadh    8u  IPv6 0x90e12861e864ee55      0t0  TCP [::1]:9004 (LISTEN)
clickhous 77385 ryadh   10u  IPv4 0x90e12861e9d8c85d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8123 (LISTEN)
clickhous 77385 ryadh   11u  IPv4 0x90e12861ebc97aed      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
clickhous 77385 ryadh   12u  IPv4 0x90e12861ead3efdd      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9004 (LISTEN)
```

Otherwise, if using ClickHouse Cloud, the ports are listed in your Cloud console (9440 for Native and 8443 for HTTP).

[image: ClickHouse Cloud - View Connection String]

Finally, a summary of all the ports used in ClickHouse is available here:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/network-ports